After upgrade 23.04 to 24.04, one user got 'Oh no, something went wrong' on login
The thing is, my second user could log-in, and the system seemed to be functioning for them. My question really is, what could have gone wrong for the 'broken' user - which files does login use that would produce a 'system is broken/ reboot' message? - and could I have fixed this issue elegantly?
(In the middle of running the upgrade I had had a warning that grub had encountered a problem and I might not be able to boot the system (at all) - at which point I would have stopped the install if I could, but there was only 'ok' and 'next', or similar, no 'cancel'. So I was kind of glad that anything worked really.)
In the end I was able to copy broken-user's files to a new-user, who could log-in - and use all the files...

Did you directly upgrade from 23.04 to 24.04 bypassing 23.10?

There was no direct supported upgrade path from 23.04 to 24.04 EXCEPT VIA RE-INSTALL, so did you re-install?   Your details show an unsupported upgrade path, thus problems may have been expected; and re-install maybe your fix.   Any config changes that occurred at 23.10 may have been missed by the user config you're having problem due to you chosen skip

Does this answer your question? Can I skip over releases when upgrading?

Sorry about the delay in clarifying, I was busy yesterday. I ONLY upgraded (I think twice from 22.04) following suggestions by Software Updater (with Updates set to 'any new version' for 'notify me of new Ubuntu version'). So, nothing beyond mainstream stuff, which has never caused problems before.

The Ubuntu Release Upgrader tool will upgrade 23.10 to 24.04, but not 23.04 to 24.04; Ubuntu 23.04 (a non-LTS) could be upgraded to the next release (23.10) but not skip a release. An LTS release can release-upgrade to a the next supported release (ie. 22.04 will currently upgrade to 23.10) which would then allow release-upgrade to 24.04; but thru 23.04 implies something unofficial to me... thus problems can be expected (it wasn't a supported upgrade thus had no QA testing).  I don't know how you forced upgrade.

I'm sorry but the question isn't really about skipping releases because I only followed recommendations  by the Software Updater, but what to do for a user who gets an 'Oh no something has gone wrong' screen on login, compared to another user who /doesn't/ get that message on the same setup.

I managed figure out that ubuntu wants you to use wayland after the upgrade.  I have a couple of programs that don't work with wayland so I got to the terminal and restored using Timeshift.
But today I fixed the issue and am working in ubuntu 24.04 with xorg.
Actions were:
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot

login into lubuntu, then:
sudo do-release-upgrade

now i can login to either lubuntu or ubuntu in xorg
